# merge two divs in a grid representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a 4x4 grid that i have put through jquery UI to make it sortable and selectable. The next thing i would like to do is to be able to merge two of the divs that i select but i've absolutely no idea as to go about this.

My first thoughts were to try to convert this to a table and toy around with colspan and rowspan attributes but this would mess up my sortable function.

If someone could point me in the right direction i would be very grateful. Basically i may reorder cells but then make a selection of two or more cells and merge them if that makes sense!

i have a JSFiddle of what i have so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fmusV/)

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="2">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="3">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="5">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="6">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="7">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="8">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="9">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="10">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="11">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id"12">12</li>
</ol>

$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" )
  .sortable({ handle: ".handle" })
  .selectable()
    .find( "li" )
      .addClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .prepend( "<div class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4'></span></div>" );
  });
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
          result.append(" #"+ ( index + 1 ) );
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

Just to also clarify, i dont mind if at this stage a blank div is created following the merge in case that s easier :)