# jQuery ui & or css3 create a matrix of divs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I don't know if there's a solution that is addressing my request using jQuery and CSS manipulation.

The objective is to use set of divs that will be with border such as draggable droppable, then they will sit in a row vs columns table like positionings.

```
  [] [] [] [] []

  [] [] [] [] []

  [] [] [] [] []
```

And when I activate the resize I want it to merge so I could keep a layout that way, as the goal is to create a layout setter app for my website pages visually.

Is there a ready solution? , if not how could I create the resize to collide and join then keep the "Data" of the layout ..

[This](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation) is the jQuery UI API, I think is close as it gets to my goal but it has no "take over" or merge.

```
            _____
  [] [] [] |    |
  [] [] [] |____|
  [] [] [] [] []
```

Comment: by the way, it seem it was already waiting for half a year (: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474579/how-to-merge-2-draggable-html-divs-into-one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767916/merge-two-divs-in-a-grid-representation